# Missing data from database with SQLite3 Python query

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, missing-data

I'm doing a query on all dates in my database. With some analysis I created it shows that I'm missing some hours. But if I check it the DB browser and do a simple SQL query as well, the value is there.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
from config import *
import datetime

connection = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create an engine.

data = pd.read_sql_query('Select * from CRYPTO_PRICES_1_HOUR WHERE crypto_id=45;', connection)

df = data[:]
print(df['start_at'])

date = 3600 # 86400=DAY, 3600=HOUR, 900=15_MIN, 300=5_MIN, 60=1_MIN
for i in df['start_at']:
    print(i)
    i = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').timestamp())
    if i - date > 3600:
        print(i - date)
        print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date))
    date = i
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you gave an example of a missing date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you're saying there are some rows in the database that do not appear in  the output from the `print(i)` at the top of the loop?

Comment: That is correct. Bit if i check my database, the value is there. Is it possible that doing a query via python skips an row sometimes?